# Simbolo > aparece no final do XML

Tags: java, xml

Eu tenho um documento XML que serve para um programa em Java salvar alguns valores que serão lidos por um outro em C#. Não é a melhor forma de trocar valores entre as linguagens (foi o que calhou, mas aceito sugestões de alternativas), mas funciona relativamente bem, o problema é que quando atualizo os valores do XML, algumas vezes (aparentemente aleatoriamente), no final do texto do XML aparece o simbolo ">", e não faço ideia do porque, e isso causa o seguinte erro:

```
[Fatal Error] test.xml:1:200: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

O XML sem erros é o seguinte: (eu identei o XML para facilitar*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="no"?>
    <Data>
        <v1>0</v1>
        <v2>0</v2>
        <v3>0</v3>
        <v4>60</v4>
        <avg>60</avg>
        <lvl1>70</lvl1>
        <lvl2>85</lvl2>
        <lvl3>100</lvl3>
        <lvl4>115</lvl4>
        <hRate>75</hRate>
    </Data>
```

Já o que tem o erro fica assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="no"?>
    <Data>
        <v1>0</v1>
        <v2>0</v2>
        <v3>0</v3>
        <v4>60</v4>
        <avg>60</avg>
        <lvl1>70</lvl1>
        <lvl2>85</lvl2>
        <lvl3>100</lvl3>
        <lvl4>115</lvl4>
        <hRate>75</hRate>
    </Data>> //ERRO NESTA LINHA
```

A parte do código que atualiza o XML é esse:

```
    public static void UpdateValuesXML(XMLParametter... param)
{
    try {
        String tempDir = System.getProperty(property); //find windows temp folder
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(tempDir + fileName);

        for (int i = 0; i < param.length; i++) 
        {
            Node val = doc.getElementsByTagName(XMLValue(param[i].param)).item(0);
            val.setTextContent(Integer.toString(param[i].value));
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(tempDir + fileName));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Comment: Esta sobrando um >, na linha que acusa o erro: </Data>> //ERRO NESTA LINHA

Comment: sim, é este o problema, este > aparece depois de um tempo que o programa esta rodando, eu não sei é porque isso aparece, porque no inicio não aparece, quando gera o arquivo XML esta como no primeiro exemplo (sem esse > a mais) e o programa corre normalmente, mas depois de um tempo (que parece ser aleatório) esse ultimo > surge

Comment: Desculpa, não tinha entendido bem o problema. Estranho isso, pois pelo que entendi não é sempre que acontece, certo? O que você poderia fazer é tratar essa informação antes de ser atualizada, tipo substituindo >> por > caso haja.

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer isso, mas não sei e não achei como fazer neste caso